# Jquery changing class when relative divs active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a couple of functions for a menu trigger (hamburger) that opens and closes a sidebar menu and in the process changes its shape from three lines to an X (standard) this is in the form of a class called active..

Here is the code ....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navToggle = $('.nav-toggle');
    $(".navbtn").click(function () {
        if($navToggle.hasClass('active')){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            $navToggle.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            $navToggle.addClass('active');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    //ALLOWS CLICK ON THE BODY TO CLOSE THE MENU//
    $(":not(#menu)").click(function(){
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');   
    });
});
```

I can't seem to get the "allow click on the body" functions to work, probably because they are getting confused with the other two functions above... can someone help me out ?

Comment: Why don't you create a Fiddle?

Comment: it wont let me add external files

Comment: Copy your external files content into code area, images are not important, simplify your html. I am not sure where is your `.navbtn` and `#menu`, but this looks like event bubbling issue.

Comment: nope didn't work , code is too complex sorry buddy , i will figure it out myself

Comment: Look, you cannot say `$(":not(#menu)").click...`, that practically means nothing, cause that means click on element which has no ID `menu` (which does not include any of `#menu` children for example). You would have to attach event as `$('body').on('click', function(e){ if( !$(this).closest('#menu').length) { ... now do something .. } })` and probably `e.stopPropagation()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: acutally $(":not(#menu)").click means anything except the div#menu will trigger the function

Comment: it would be great if i could say .body (but not #menu).click

Comment: You can, look at my comment above. There is no other way to do it. Your `#menu` contains other elements and when you click them they do not have id `menu`.

Comment: dd what you said including the stoppropagation

Comment: and t worked thank you for your insight !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your body content wrapped some type of container . You could just add the click function to your container.

Example.

```
$(".container").click(function(){
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
        $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not my answer but i wanted the person who commented earlier to receive credit and other than voting him up i wanted to make sure t was official to help others... he indeed had the answer and this is how it went ....

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
 if( !$(this).closest('#menu').length) {
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
        event.stopPropagation();        

            };


});
```